# Static to Instance method trampolining with templates

Tags: c++, c++11, template, trampoline

I finally have a working trampoline mechanism. Would anyone care to critique it?

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/vOtbcD)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <map>

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:    
    typedef void (T::*PFunc)(void);
    typedef void (*PHandler)(void*);

    using method_map_t = map< string, PHandler >;
    static method_map_t& methods( ) {
        static method_map_t* map_of_methods{};
        if( ! map_of_methods ) map_of_methods = new method_map_t;
        return *map_of_methods;
    }

    static void register_method( string name, PHandler handler ) {
        methods()[name] = handler;
    }

    // generic trampoline
    template<PFunc sig>
    static void Handler( void* pInstance ) {
        T* f = reinterpret_cast<T*>(pInstance);
        (f ->* sig)();
    }
};
```

...

```
class Final : Base<Final>
{
public:
    void Foo(){cout<<"got foo";}
    void Bar(){cout<<"got bar";}

    static void init(){
        // register_method populates a table of "extern C" function pointers.
        register_method( "foo", static_cast<PHandler>( &Handler<&Final::Foo> ) );
        register_method( "bar", static_cast<PHandler>( &Handler<&Final::Bar> ) );
    }
};

void InvokeFromC(void* inst, string name) {
    Base<Final>::PHandler h = Base<Final>::methods()[name];
    (*h)(inst);
}

int main() {
    Final* f = new Final{};
    f->init();
    // simulate invoking from C 
    InvokeFromC( f, "foo" );

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

This question follows from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934036/coding-static-to-instance-method-trampoline-function-with-templates/).

Answer (score 1):

I will maintain my list of improvements in this answer.

There is a more succinct way to expose the mechanism to the consumer:

```
class Final : Base<Final>
{
    register_method<&Final::Foo>( "foo" ); //, static_cast<PHandler>( &Handler<&Final::Foo> ) );
    register_method<&Final::Bar>( "bar" ); //, static_cast<PHandler>( &Handler<&Final::Bar> ) );
    :

class Base
{
    :
    template<PFunc func>
    static void register_method( string name ) {
        methods()[name] = &Handler<func>;
    }
    :
```

This has extra advantage in that it avoids the following nasty issue:

> Note: (Eelis on IRC) gcc is known not to be able to resolve addresses
>   of function template specializations passed to functions. You can work
>   around it either by declaring separate variables for the function
>   pointers, or using a dirty cast (or a nice cast like
>   boost::implicit_cast)

It doubles the number of templated functions getting generated: now 2 are generated for each method instead of one. But at a small price, it is much cleaner to the consumer!

Also function pointer typedef-s could be rewritten:

```
//typedef void (T::*PFunc)(void);
//typedef void (*PHandler)(void*);

using PFunc = void (T::*)(void);
using PHandler = void(*)(void);
```

http://ideone.com/ZFQb1f